# Java (Netbeans) - how to code for "access denied" in the if statement, i tried the best but it didnt work..?

Tags: java, sql

Need to create three user logins, once logged in each loginuser need to have a different interface. My action button script follows:

```
 try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=77OOP062;user=sa;password=hnd";
                Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                String sql ="Select Type from Users where Username=? and Password=?";
                PreparedStatement pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, jTextFieldUserName.getText());
                pst.setString(2, jTextFieldPassword.getText());
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                rs.next();
                String name = rs.getString("Type");





            if (name.equals("admin")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Permitted");
        ManageUI ah = new ManageUI();
        ah.setVisible(true);
            }

            if (name.equals("cashier")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Permitted");
            CashierUI eh = new CashierUI();
            eh.setVisible(true);
    }
            else if (name.equals("stockkeeper")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Permitted");
        StockKeeperUI aq = new StockKeeperUI();
            aq.setVisible(true);
    }
            conn.close();
        }
       catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }


This is my Sql server database: User
-----------------------------------------------
Username | Type         | Password |
-----------------------------------------------
mick     | admin        |   123    |  
-----------------------------------------------
nisha    | cashier      |   456    | 
-----------------------------------------------
sam      | stockkeeper  |   789    | 
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: my code is working but i need to add on the "access denied code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgotten what to do when nothing matches that is last else in the following code also at second if include else to complete the if else chain.

```
 try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=77OOP062;user=sa;password=hnd";
                Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                String sql ="Select Type from Users where Username=? and Password=?";
                PreparedStatement pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, jTextFieldUserName.getText());
                pst.setString(2, jTextFieldPassword.getText());
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){ // Row Exists
                String name = rs.getString("Type");

    if (name.equals("admin")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Permitted");
            ManageUI ah = new ManageUI();
            ah.setVisible(true);
                }

                else if (name.equals("cashier")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Permitted");
                CashierUI eh = new CashierUI();
                eh.setVisible(true);
        }
                else if (name.equals("stockkeeper")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Permitted");
            StockKeeperUI aq = new StockKeeperUI();
                aq.setVisible(true);
        }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Denied");
        }
  } else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Denied"); // Row Doesnot exists
}
    conn.close();
    }
   catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the instant message. i tried the code no i am getting this message: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQServerException: The result has no current row.

Comment: You should handle what to do when there is no such user. Updated my code check.

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest* answer is `else`. Add an `else` before the `if` for `cashier` and then one more `else` for the "default" **access denied** case. Like,

```
if (name.equals("admin")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Permitted");
    ManageUI ah = new ManageUI();
    ah.setVisible(true);
} else if (name.equals("cashier")) { // <-- add an else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Permitted");
    CashierUI eh = new CashierUI();
    eh.setVisible(true);
} else if (name.equals("stockkeeper")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Permitted");
    StockKeeperUI aq = new StockKeeperUI();
    aq.setVisible(true);
} else { // <-- another else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Denied");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the instant message. i tried the code no i am getting this message: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQServerException: The result has no current row.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (name.equals("stockkeeper")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Permitted");
    StockKeeperUI aq = new StockKeeperUI();
        aq.setVisible(true);
} else{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Denied"); //if there is no matching as Admin, Cashier ,Stockkeeper then else part executed
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the instant message. i tried the code no i am getting this message: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQServerException: The result has no current row.